# Sort result on elasticSearch by field weight AND a date

Tags: elasticsearch

I use elasticsearch to return article who contains a certains words in some fields. I have weighted those field in order to have the most "important" field matching comming first.

Now I have to , in case of equity, sort the equivalent hit according to some date field.

How can I do it?

my query:

```
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "some text in the fields",
          "fields" : [
            "unimportantField^1.0",
            "anotherField^3.0",
            "mainField^4.0"
          ],
          "type" : "best_fields",
          "default_operator" : "or",
        ...
        }
      },
      {
        "match" : {
     ...
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Comment: have you seen https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/sort-search-results.html?

Answer (score 0):

Add sort on score and date field

```
"sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "date": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
```